# get started with wildfly confusing

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial how to get started with a JEE application using *WildFly* server?

I am little confused right now cause at first I decided to start with an official website of the wildfly. 
I found some guide links in there and seems like a half of pages are not found or missed.

For example, they have a [Getting Started Developing Applications Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Getting+Started+Developing+Applications+Guide) link, when I go there there is another one link which leads to the [github page](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/master/guide/Introduction.asciidoc) and returns 404 page.

Ok then, i wen to github page with documentation and found following section which describes a list of [quickstarts](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart#available-quickstarts).

So as it says

> Quickstarts with tutorials in the [Get Started Developing Applications](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart#suggested-approach-to-the-quickstarts) are noted with two asterisks ( ** ) following the quickstart name.

But again if you go to this link it is not found as well and so on.

To be honest I am kind of tired of this confused documentation so I am looking for a best approach how to get my JEE application up and running using *WildFly* as a server container.

So any suggestions would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get started with Java EE then have a look at the [Java EE 7 tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/).

If you're looking to just start WildFly so that you can deploy an application you simple download the zip, extract it and use either `bin/standalone.sh` or `bin\standalone.bat` to start it. You can get further information about getting started with WildFly [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Getting+Started+Guide).

The [quickstarts](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/9.x) are good examples of some simple applications that can be deployed. The [README](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/9.x#wildfly-quickstarts) is pretty descriptive on how the quickstarts themselves work, but isn't meant to be a Java EE 7 tutorial.